# How to use hide function inside if statement

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I click `.dot` element it should query database and show the result, and in second click it should hide the result. However it just show nothing in first click.

When I leave second `if` empty it successfully  queries the database and show the result. But when I add  this code `$(".conte").hide();` to second `if` it shows nothing in click.

here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var do1 = 0;
  var do2 = 0;
  var do3 = 0;
  var do4 = 0;

  $('.dot1').click(function() {

    if (do1 == 0) {
      do2 = 0; // for other function
      do3 = 0; // for other function
      do4 = 0; // for other function
      do1 = 1;

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "query1.php",
        success: function(data) {
          $(".conte").html(data);
        }
      });
    }
    if (do1 == 1) {
      $(".conte").hide();
      do1 = 0;
      //hide me
    }
    // $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you looked in the browser console for errors?

Comment: Found the mistake after 5 hours, it should be else if

Comment: @Tabriz - If you think you found your answer and it is useful and not just a syntax error, I suggest putting your solution in an answer and marking it as a solution. Otherwise, I would delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you send the AJAX request in the first `if`, you do `do1 = 1;`. So when you then test `if (do1 == 1)`, this is successful, so you hide `.conte`.

Change the second `if` to `else if`, so you don't run both blocks in the same click. Or use `else` if these are the only two possible values.

If you're using these for binary states, it's better style to use `true` and `false`, not `0` and `1`. Then you can write:

```
do1 = true;

if (do1) {
    do1 = false;
    ...
} else {
    do1 = true;
    ...
}
```